# Razor Pages - Refresh Page from Partial View After Updated Data

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to figure out how to refresh the page from Partial View after updated data, but I am stuck.

Here is my index.cshtml page:

```
@page
@model RazorPagesCollection.Pages.PopUp.IndexModel
@using Northwind_EF.Models
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#CustomerGrid .details").click(function () {
                var customerId = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Index?handler=GetDetails",
                    headers:
                    {
                        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    data: { "customerId": customerId },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#partialModal").find(".modal-body").html(response);
                        $("#partialModal").modal('show');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });


            $("#CustomerGrid .updatePopup").click(function () {
                var customerId = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Index?handler=UpdateRecordView",
                    headers:
                    {
                        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    data: { "customerId": customerId },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#partialModal").find(".modal-body").html(response);
                        $("#partialModal").modal('show');
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });

            
            $("#divCustomer .updatePost").on("click", function (e) {
                console.log("Posting Form Data....");
                var customerId = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(0).html();
                var data = $("#form1").serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Index?handler=UpdateRecord",
                    data: data,
                    headers:
                    {
                        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#partialModal").modal('hide');
                        $("#CustomerGrid").load("index #CustomerGrid");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });

        });



        function PostProcessFormID(id) {
            //check valid if you have client side validation...
            valid = $('#' + id).valid();
            console.log("id: " + valid);

            if (valid) {
                thisForm = document.getElementById(id);
                var data = new FormData(thisForm);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Index?handler=UpdateRecord",
                    data: data,
                    headers:
                    {
                        "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $("#partialModal").modal('hide');
                        $("#CustomerGrid").load("index #CustomerGrid");
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <h4>Customers</h4>
    <hr />
    <div id="divCustomer">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-responsive" id="CustomerGrid">
            <tr>
                <th>CustomerID</th>
                <th>Company Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (Customer customer in Model.Customers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@customer.CustomerID</td>
                    <td>@customer.CompanyName</td>
                    <td>@customer.City</td>
                    <td>@customer.Country</td>
                    <td><a class="details" href="javascript:;">View</a></td>
                    <td><a class="updatePopup" href="javascript:;">Update</a></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="partialModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">Customer Details Form</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" id="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary updatePost">Update</button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-Behind of Index.cshtml.cs page:

```
using EF_DBContext;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Northwind_EF.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RazorPagesCollection.Pages.PopUp
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {

        private NorthwinDbContext Context { get; }
        public IndexModel(NorthwinDbContext _context)
        {
            this.Context = _context;
        }

        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            this.Customers = (from customer in this.Context.Customers.Take(10)
                              select customer).ToList();
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnPostGetDetails(string customerId)
        {
            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "Details",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Customer>(ViewData, this.Context.Customers.Find(customerId))
            };
        }

        public PartialViewResult OnPostUpdateRecordView(string customerId)
        {
            return new PartialViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "Update",
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<Customer>(ViewData, this.Context.Customers.Find(customerId))
            };
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostUpdateRecord(Customer customer)
        {
            Customer updatedCustomer = (from c in this.Context.Customers
                                        where c.CustomerID == customer.CustomerID
                                        select c).FirstOrDefault();

            if (updatedCustomer != null)
            {
                updatedCustomer.CompanyName = customer.CompanyName ;
                updatedCustomer.Country = customer.Country;
                this.Context.SaveChanges();
                //ViewData["Message"] = "Customer record updated.";
                return Content("Updated Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Updated Failed");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The Partial View update page:

```
@model Northwind_EF.Models.Customer
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<form id="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="PostProcessFormID('form1'); return false;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><input asp-for="CompanyName" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Address</th>
            <td><input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <td><input asp-for="City" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <td><input asp-for="Country" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>PostalCode</th>
            <td><input asp-for="PostalCode" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-dark" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="CustomerID" asp-for="CustomerID" value="@Model.CustomerID" />
</form>
```

Post Updated (after suggestions from @pcalkins:
The above code works fine for freshing the page after updated data.  However, the Update button on table list view only works once time. Since the reload the table content breaks the update event, how do I rebind the event Update again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Right now you are letting the <FORM> send the POST directly to the controller.  You'd want to use Ajax, as you did for the other handlers, so that the JS receives the callback.  (Don't return redirect, but only something to say things were validated and updated without error.... or the error that happened.)  You can then update the DOM from the JS on the callback.  Right now you're returning HTML of partialviews for the other handlers.  You could do the same with the form...ex:  $("#divCustomer").html(response);   For cancel just call $("#partialModal").modal('hide'); ?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I followed your suggestions and got it works correctly now.  However, I am facing another problem is that it only works the fist click on Update button on list view. I used `$("#partialModal").modal('hide');` to hide the popup and `$("#CustomerGrid").load("index #CustomerGrid");` to refresh the table after AJAX posted successfully.  I think reload the table breaks the binding for the Jquery onclick for the Update button. Any suggestion?

Comment: Re-do the binding on the callback... after populating on the callback, you can call $("#CustomerGrid .update").click(function ().... to reset the handler. Or use in-line handlers generated in the CSHTML file and handle events globally. (handle events according to source of event (event.target) received...)

Comment: I have updated the post to show the updated code.  I have no idea  how to "re-do the biding" or "use inline handlers".  Would you please post the code for those two methods (using my example if possible).  Thanks!

Comment: I'd consider changing your strategy to using ".on()"... this will respond to events instead of setting event handlers on page load.  See here: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Comment: I just did using `$("#divCustomer .updatePost").on("click", function (e) {`, but still not working.  The update button only works the first time.  please advise.

Comment: The basic issue is that you are setting event handlers on page load.  When the div is updated, you no longer have handlers attached.  You probably want to just put that ajax call in a function and call that from a handler that's either in-line "onClick='sendForm('form1')"... put that in the CSHTML... or responds to events that bubble up to the document/body level.

Comment: I'll try and bang out a quick example of the concept...

Comment: I am a little lost.  Thanks for looking in a quick example.  I am new to Razor pages stuff and trying to learning that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the simplest way to go since I think you're only using jQuery in this one spot...

in your partial:

```
<form id="form1" onsubmit="PostProcessFormID('form1'); return false;>
```

in your script:

```
 function PostProcessFormID(id) {
 //check valid if you have client side validation...  
 valid = $('#' + id).valid();


   if (valid) {
    
    thisForm = document.getElementById(id);
    var data = new FormData(thisForm);
  //do your AJAX call...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  But  I still get the same problem only works the first time.  I have updated the post with the Partial View page and index.cshtml page with your suggested function.  Please take a look of the post.

Comment: do the same for your customer grid clicks.  Use onclick="ProcessUpdate(passing whatever's needed here... customerID?)

Comment: thanks again. I got it works correctly now.  I followed your suggestion originally, put the Jquery event in a function, call that function when the page loads initially, and then call it again after the AJAX success.